# Insert edittext in databasehelper class

Tags: android, sqlite, select, insert, sql-delete

This is My Database Class. In this I want to insert the data in to the database in the run time. Another class I have edittext while clicking the button the edittext value is inserted in to the database but it is not inserted, how it can be done in this class?

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "employee_directory1";

        public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
                super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
                /*


public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
                /*
                 * Create the employee table and populate it with sample data.
                 * In step 6, we will move these hardcoded statements to an XML document.
                 */
                String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS employee (" +
                                                "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + 
                                                "firstName TEXT, " +
                                                "lastName TEXT, " +
                                                "title TEXT, " +
                                                "officePhone TEXT, " +
                                                "cellPhone TEXT, " +
                                                "email TEXT, " +
                                                "managerId INTEGER)";
                db.execSQL(sql);

                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

                values.put("firstName", "John");
                values.put("lastName", "Smith");
                values.put("title", "CEO");
                values.put("officePhone", "617-219-2001");
                values.put("cellPhone", "617-456-7890");
                values.put("email", "jsmith@email.com");
                db.insert("employee", null, values);



        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
                db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS employees");
                onCreate(db);


        }

}
```

Comment: You've posted the databaseclass: it does not do much more then create a database and insert a sample row. Wouldn't it be better if you show your actual code with the button and what you are doing to insert there?

Comment: @nanne  this is the code for inserting edittext value,but it shows error in database class
         Savemedicine.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
     try {
      db.open();
      String med=Medicines.getText().toString();
      String dos1=Dose1.getText().toString();
      String dos2=Dose2.getText().toString();
      String dos3=Dose3.getText().toString();
      
      db.getMedicine( med, dos1, dos2, dos3);

Comment: Please provide the stacktrace of the error from your logcat

Answer (score 0):

refer this code and correct your changes

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class RegistrationOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "REGISTRATION_DB";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "REGISTRATION_TABLE";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME_ONE = "REGISTRATION_TABLE_ONE";
    public static final int VERSION = 1;
    public static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
    public static final String FNAME = "F_NAME";
    public static final String PKEY_ID = "pid";
    public static final String PROFILE = "profile";
    public static final String LNAME = "L_NAME";
    public static final String SCRIPT = "create table " + TABLE_NAME + " ("
            + KEY_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + FNAME
            + " text not null, " + LNAME + " text not null );";

    public static final String PROFILE_TABLE = "create table " + TABLE_NAME_ONE + " ("
            + PKEY_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + PROFILE
            + " text not null, );";

  /* public static final String PROFILE_TABLE="create table profiletable(profileid integer primary key autoincrement,profilename text null);";
   public static final String VALUE_TABLE="create table valuetable(id integer primary key autoincrement,value text null,delay );";
   */


    public RegistrationOpenHelper(Context context, String name,
            CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, name, factory, version);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL(SCRIPT);
        db.execSQL(PROFILE_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("drop table " + TABLE_NAME);
        db.execSQL("drop table "+TABLE_NAME_ONE);
        onCreate(db);
    }

}
```

apater.java

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;

public class RegistrationAdapter {
    SQLiteDatabase database_ob;
    RegistrationOpenHelper openHelper_ob;
    Context context;

    public RegistrationAdapter(Context c) {
        context = c;
    }

    public RegistrationAdapter opnToRead() {
        openHelper_ob = new RegistrationOpenHelper(context,
                openHelper_ob.DATABASE_NAME, null, openHelper_ob.VERSION);
        database_ob = openHelper_ob.getReadableDatabase();
        return this;

    }

    public RegistrationAdapter opnToWrite() {
        openHelper_ob = new RegistrationOpenHelper(context,
                openHelper_ob.DATABASE_NAME, null, openHelper_ob.VERSION);
        database_ob = openHelper_ob.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;

    }

    public void Close() {
        database_ob.close();
    }

    public long insertDetails(String fname, String lname) {
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(openHelper_ob.FNAME, fname);
        contentValues.put(openHelper_ob.LNAME, lname);
        opnToWrite();
        long val = database_ob.insert(openHelper_ob.TABLE_NAME, null,
                contentValues);
        Close();
        return val;

    }

    public Cursor queryName() {
        String[] cols = { openHelper_ob.KEY_ID, openHelper_ob.FNAME,
                openHelper_ob.LNAME };
        opnToWrite();
        Cursor c = database_ob.query(openHelper_ob.TABLE_NAME, cols, null,
                null, null, null, null);

        return c;

    }

    public Cursor queryAll(int nameId) {
        String[] cols = { openHelper_ob.KEY_ID, openHelper_ob.FNAME,
                openHelper_ob.LNAME };
        opnToWrite();
        Cursor c = database_ob.query(openHelper_ob.TABLE_NAME, cols,
                openHelper_ob.KEY_ID + "=" + nameId, null, null, null, null);

        return c;

    }

    public long updateldetail(int rowId, String fname, String lname) {
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(openHelper_ob.FNAME, fname);
        contentValues.put(openHelper_ob.LNAME, lname);
        opnToWrite();
        long val = database_ob.update(openHelper_ob.TABLE_NAME, contentValues,
                openHelper_ob.KEY_ID + "=" + rowId, null);
        Close();
        return val;
    }

    public int deletOneRecord(int rowId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        opnToWrite();
        int val = database_ob.delete(openHelper_ob.TABLE_NAME,
                openHelper_ob.KEY_ID + "=" + rowId, null);
        Close();
        return val;
    }

}
```